# JS Number function convert this string "1,255,558.3652" appear "Nan"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use `Number("1,255,558.3652")` to convert this string  to number,but the result in console tells me "Nan".

In my html code,I use:

```
 <input id="text_target_value" class="text-right number" type="text" onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[^\d{1,}\.\d{1,}|^\d{1,}\%|\d{1,}]/g,'')"/>
```

to format the input,when I use:

```
var page_goal_val=Number($("#text_target_value").val());
```

to get the value,it said "Nan",so what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Number` doesn't recognize numeric strings with commas in them. Strip out all the commas first:

```js
console.log(Number(
  "1,255,558.3652".replace(/,/g, '')
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `input` element allows the values such as `123....123`. And if you do:

```
Number(
  "123....123".replace(/,/g, '')
)
```

It will still give you `NaN`. To prevent from that and also as recommended for floating values, use `parseFloat()` instead of `Number()`. Using that, it will prevent from `NaN` output:

You get **1245634** (but not NaN) which should be correct

```
parseFloat(
  "12,456,34...123".replace(/,/g, '')
);
```

```js
console.log(parseFloat(
  "12,456,34...123".replace(/,/g, '')
));
```

You get **1234564.123**

```
parseFloat(
  "1,234,564.123".replace(/,/g, '')
);
```

```js
console.log(parseFloat(
  "1,234,564.123".replace(/,/g, '')
));
```